# Next Position with Point2D java

Tags: java

I am building a traffic simulator and now I need to avoid car collisions.

I have all my cars in  a `List`, and my idea is to go through the list, but I don´t know how to get the next position of my car to see if it's empty, and if it is, the car can continue.

```
public boolean isClear(Car car) {
    for(Car c : listaCar) {
        if(car.getPosition.equals(c.getPosition()))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
} 


// from car class, getPosition()

public Point2D getPosition() {
    return position;
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what are you trying to do? care to elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Particularly: What is the "next position"? Are you changing the position somewhere (maybe based on a velocity?)

Comment: Just a remark: you could run into the following problem: at timestep t_0 position x,y is empty. But at timestep t_1 two cars want both to occupy that position, but since you are checking for the position being free at t_0 it seems for both cars fine to move. If you are moving one car after the other this might not be a problem though... so in short: the answer to your question depends a lot on how you move the cars and how you simulate time, etc... as it stands, I don't think there is a clear unique solution to your problem...